# Laravel test class property not persisting

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

I'm trying to set a `sensorId` property that will be used by every method in my feature test. The problem is that it is not persisting between tests.

Here is my test class:

```
class LogApiPostTest extends TestCase
{
    public $sensorId;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->sensorId = 'SEN' . rand(10000000, 999999999);
    }

    public function test_creates_sensor()
    {
        $response = $this->post('/api/logs', $this->data([
            //
        ]));

        $response->assertStatus(200);
        $response->assertSeeText('Sensor created');
    }

    public function test_updates_sensor()
    {
        $response = $this->post('/api/logs', $this->data([
            //
        ]));

        $response->assertStatus(200);
        $response->assertSeeText('Sensor updated');
    }

    public function test_creates_car()
    {
        $response = $this->post('/api/logs', $this->data([
            'CarID' => 'B',
        ]));

        $response->assertStatus(200);
        $response->assertSeeText('Car created');
    }

    public function test_updates_car()
    {
        $response = $this->post('/api/logs', $this->data([
            'CarID' => 'B',
        ]));

        $response->assertStatus(200);
        $response->assertSeeText('Car updated');
    }

    public function test_is_unauthorized()
    {
        $response = $this->post('/api/logs', $this->data([
            'token_id' => 'thisShouldntWork',
        ]));

        $response->assertUnauthorized();
    }

    public function data($merge = [])
    {
        return array_merge([
            'token_id' => config('api.token'),
            'sensorID' => $this->sensorId,
            'CarID' => 'A',
            'LogType' => 'CarLog',
            'Time' => time(),
            'DrctnFlr' => '-02',
            'MCSS' => 'STB',
            'OpMode' => 'INA',
            'DoorStats' => '][**',
            'DoorCmd' => 'C6:C1>',
            'OCSS' => 'GTN02',
            'Load' => '002%',
        ], $merge);
    }
}
```

I just want the `sensorId` property to persist for all tests in this class.

Answer (score 1):

When there is a dependency between tests, you must use the `@depends` annotation.
This allows to ensure the execution order of tests is correct and also to pass values between tests. Instead of making `sensorId` to persist, just pass it from test to test.

https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#test-dependencies